# How to remove some values from a python dictionary

Tags: python

I have this python dictionary `myDict`:

```
{'Age': {0: '39'}, 'DailyRate': {0: '903'}, 'DistanceFromHome': {0: '2'}, 'EnvironmentSatisfaction': {0: '1'}, 'HourlyRate': {0: '41'}, 'JobInvolvement': {0: '4'}, 'JobLevel': {0: '3'}, 'JobSatisfaction': {0: '3'}, 'MonthlyIncome': {0: '7880'}, 'MonthlyRate': {0: '2560'}, 'NumCompaniesWorked': {0: '0'}, 'PercentSalaryHike': {0: '18'}, 'RelationshipSatisfaction': {0: '4'}, 'StandardHours': {0: '80'}, 'TotalWorkingYears': {0: '9'}, 'TrainingTimesLastYear': {0: '3'}, 'YearsAtCompany': {0: '8'}, 'YearsInCurrentRole': {0: '7'}, 'YearsSinceLastPromotion': {0: '0'}, 'YearsWithCurrManager': {0: '7'}, 'MaritalStatus_': {0: '2'}, 'JobRole_': {0: '7'}, 'Gender_': {0: '1'}, 'EducationField_': {0: '1'}, 'Department_': {0: '2'}, 'BusinessTravel_': {0: '2'}, 'OverTime_': {0: '1'}, 'Over18_': {0: '1'}}
```

As you can see, if i get a one from above sample as below,

```
{'Age': {0: '39'}}
```

There is an additional `0` in front of the value `39`. And this zero presents in every key-value pair.

How can I get rid of this `0`, so it looks like this:

```
{'Age': '39'}
```

I tried this method, but it removes the whole key instead of the `0`:

```
map(myDict.pop, ['Age',''])
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for `{k: v[0] for k, v in myDict.items()}`?

Comment: Hi, what is `k`, `v` here?

Comment: That's not _removing_ values, that's _transforming_ values.

Comment: can you provide a complete answer? I am confused. Sorry for that.

Comment: your dict is wrong. becouse Age is a dict of ages.

Comment: @JananathBanuka `k,v` are just arbitrary variable names, standing for `key` and `value`.

Comment: @0x5453 that should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: Why are you creating it like that in the first place?

Comment: It is not something I created, it is generated from when a pandas dataframe is converted to a dictionary.

Comment: "created", "generated" ... potato, potato. I'm not familiar with pandas, but I find it hard to believe that it can't be done right, i.e., so that you get your desired result directly. And perhaps you should ask about *that*.

Comment: @Heap Overflow, there might be better ways of solving this when working with Pandas, but the knowledge of this question will be useful nonetheless.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use dictionary comprehension to solve this issue. Try doing:

```py
new_dict = {key: value[0] for key, value in old_dict.items()}
```

Here, you iterate through each `key, value` pair in the dictiory and assign the key of the new dictionary to the key of the old dictionary. But the value becomes the 0th key value of the dictionary inside the dictionary.

For an example, the `key` starts at `'Age'`, so the first key of the new dictionary is `'Age'`. The value however is `{0: '39'}[0]` which is `'39'`. So the first element of the dictionary is `'Age': '39'`

Comment: Great! I would appreciate it if you could accept the answer if this helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

you can read it by the following code:

```
dict= {'Age': {0: '39'}, 'DailyRate': {0: '903'}, 'DistanceFromHome': {0: '2'}, 'EnvironmentSatisfaction': {0: '1'}, 'HourlyRate': {0: '41'}, 'JobInvolvement': {0: '4'}, 'JobLevel': {0: '3'}, 'JobSatisfaction': {0: '3'}, 'MonthlyIncome': {0: '7880'}, 'MonthlyRate': {0: '2560'}, 'NumCompaniesWorked': {0: '0'}, 'PercentSalaryHike': {0: '18'}, 'RelationshipSatisfaction': {0: '4'}, 'StandardHours': {0: '80'}, 'TotalWorkingYears': {0: '9'}, 'TrainingTimesLastYear': {0: '3'}, 'YearsAtCompany': {0: '8'}, 'YearsInCurrentRole': {0: '7'}, 'YearsSinceLastPromotion': {0: '0'}, 'YearsWithCurrManager': {0: '7'}, 'MaritalStatus_': {0: '2'}, 'JobRole_': {0: '7'}, 'Gender_': {0: '1'}, 'EducationField_': {0: '1'}, 'Department_': {0: '2'}, 'BusinessTravel_': {0: '2'}, 'OverTime_': {0: '1'}, 'Over18_': {0: '1'}}
print(dict['Age'][0])
```

to convert just do:

```
age = dict['Age'][0]
del(dict['Age'])
dict.update({"Age":age})
```

you will get the following dic as result:

```
{'DailyRate': {0: '903'}, 'DistanceFromHome': {0: '2'}, 'EnvironmentSatisfaction': {0: '1'}, 'HourlyRate': {0: '41'}, 'JobInvolvement': {0: '4'}, 'JobLevel': {0: '3'}, 'JobSatisfaction': {0: '3'}, 'MonthlyIncome': {0: '7880'}, 'MonthlyRate': {0: '2560'}, 'NumCompaniesWorked': {0: '0'}, 'PercentSalaryHike': {0: '18'}, 'RelationshipSatisfaction': {0: '4'}, 'StandardHours': {0: '80'}, 'TotalWorkingYears': {0: '9'}, 'TrainingTimesLastYear': {0: '3'}, 'YearsAtCompany': {0: '8'}, 'YearsInCurrentRole': {0: '7'}, 'YearsSinceLastPromotion': {0: '0'}, 'YearsWithCurrManager': {0: '7'}, 'MaritalStatus_': {0: '2'}, 'JobRole_': {0: '7'}, 'Gender_': {0: '1'}, 'EducationField_': {0: '1'}, 'Department_': {0: '2'}, 'BusinessTravel_': {0: '2'}, 'OverTime_': {0: '1'}, 'Over18_': {0: '1'}, 'Age': '39'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try the following code:

```
keys = myDict.keys()
valuesWithZero = myDict.values()

valuesNoZero = []
for item in valuesWithZero:
    value_iterator = iter(item.values()) #to make dict_values obj iterable
    first_value = next(value_iterator) #obtaining first value
    valuesNoZero.append(first_value) #adding to new list
    

newDict = dict(zip(keys, valuesNoZero))  #combining keys arr and values arr
print(newDict)

# should output: {'Age': '39', 'DailyRate': '903', 'DistanceFromHome': '2', 'EnvironmentSatisfaction': '1', 'HourlyRate': '41', 'JobInvolvement': '4', 'JobLevel': '3', 'JobSatisfaction': '3', 'MonthlyIncome': '7880', 'MonthlyRate': '2560', 'NumCompaniesWorked': '0', 'PercentSalaryHike': '18', 'RelationshipSatisfaction': '4', 'StandardHours': '80', 'TotalWorkingYears': '9', 'TrainingTimesLastYear': '3', 'YearsAtCompany': '8', 'YearsInCurrentRole': '7', 'YearsSinceLastPromotion': '0', 'YearsWithCurrManager': '7', 'MaritalStatus_': '2', 'JobRole_': '7', 'Gender_': '1', 'EducationField_': '1', 'Department_': '2', 'BusinessTravel_': '2', 'OverTime_': '1', 'Over18_': '1'}
```

Comment: You should start learning how to write `pythonic` code

Answer (score 0):

Same process as the accepted answer but uses some of Python's *functional* features.

```
import operator
zero = operator.itemgetter(0)

newdict = dict(zip(myDict,map(zero, myDict.values())))
```